# The [paint-code] tag has the wrong spelling: the name should not have any spaces or separators

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I noticed this tag [paint-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paint-code) is basically spelled incorrectly,

the product is just "paintcode" - there's never been a space or hyphen.

(Glance at their website to check this - paintcodeapp.com )

Comment: @Cody perhaps add a synonym for the old, wrong spelling too?

Comment: Should I, @Erik? Why? I considered it, but other than the possibility of breaking links, I didn't see the point.

Comment: People apparently got the spelling wrong, else the tag with the wrong spelling would never have been created, and it got used a couple of times. I guess I was just surprised you didn't, thought it was standard practice, but I can imagine it's so small it doesn't really matter

Comment: adding a synonym to wrong spelling is an incredibly bad idea, guys

Comment: Why? We have tons of synonyms to redirect wrong to correct spelling.